# Date and Time Validation Checking in freemarker

Tags: date, validation, time, freemarker, smooks

I would like to check the given date and time against the following formats.
Date -- {YYYYMMDD},
Time need to check with four formats -- {HHMM, or HHMMSS, or HHMMSSD, or HHMMSSDD}
Above date and time formats needs to be checked using freemarker,
How to check and validate in freemarker? ..
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Validation (like input validation) is normally not done in templates. So if you parse strings with `?date(pattern)`/`?time(pattern)`, and the format doesn't match, the whole template terminates with error. If you just need to figure out which of those formats a string input is in, you could use the length (`?length`) and/or regular expressions (`?matches(regexp)`).